# How to get indicator value with quantmod?

Tags: r, quantmod

I am new with quantmod so I guess this is pretty simple, although I couldn't find an answer.

I am trying to access the indicator value in order to store it into a variable and be able to manipulate it.

Right now I understand how to chart an indicator, but not how to access the values forming the chart.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You need to be more specific.   Post your code and you'll get a better response.

Comment: Hello Bill, thanks for your time. There is not much I can add to my question. I want to be able to access the different indicators values. For example when I run 'GOOG['::']' I would like to have another column with the MACD() data.

I want to be able to do 'value<-MACDvalue' but I don't know how to get the MACDvalue.

Comment: Again, you need to post some code to get a response.    Here's a blog that might have some examples http://blog.fosstrading.com/2011/03/how-to-backtest-strategy-in-r.html

Comment: Hey Bill, thanks again! This is what I was looking for MyVar<-MACD(GOOG,12,26,9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone bumping into this thread and looking for a similar answer, it is pretty simple:

```
MyVar <- MACD(GOOG, 12, 26, 9)
```

Comment: You could also accept your own answer, makes it clear that this question was answered, and gets you some rep :).

Comment: Thanks, I can't till tomorrow. I don't know whats up with all those negative rep with this question.

Comment: I do not uwe quantmod myself, but your question is short and a big vague. A large of this vagueness is caused by lack of a snippet or R code which shows your problem, and which we can run on our own computers.

Comment: well, goal of the question was to understand if there was any function which could do what I was asking, if I knew the code there would not be any reason for the question. In the same way a question asking how to create a candle chart will not have any code, mine was towards understanding if there was any function which would give me the indicators value. Anyway, I am sure someone will find my question useful.

Comment: I don't think there was a question wether the question was relevant, it was just that some example R code was missing.